# Bubble / satellite diagram with children

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, tikz-styles, smartdiagram

I've got the following code with Latex `smartdiagram` package that produces the attached bubble diagram.

But I would like to be able **to have child satellites** in it (see prototype image below).

- Is it possible to do so with `smartdiagram`? If not, how could I replicate this directly with `tikz` or or similar?

Thanks!

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
    bubble center node font = \footnotesize,
    bubble node font = \footnotesize,
    % specifies the minimum size of the bubble center node
    bubble center node size = 0.1cm,
    %  specifies the minimum size of the bubbles
    bubble node size = 0.9cm,
    % specifies which is the distance among the bubble center node and the other bubbles
    distance center/other bubbles = 0.5cm,
    % sets the distance from the text to the border of the bubble center node
    %distance text center bubble = 0.5cm,
}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
    \normalsize{Interest} \\ \normalsize{Areas},
    \textbf{DLTs/} \\ \textbf{Blockchain,} \\ \textbf{Web3},
    \textbf{Big/Fast Data} \\ \textbf{\& Streaming},    
    \textbf{Artificial} \\ \textbf{Intelligence},
    \textbf{Functional} \\ \textbf{Programming}
}

\end{document}
```

### What I have vs. what I want

[image: What I have vs. what I want]

### What I tried

I tried replacing the satellite `Functional Programming` by a new diagram, with the aim of the satellite to become a new planet, so can have more satellites (the children). But the result was a mess. I mean:

`\textbf{Functional} \\ \textbf{Programming}` to
`\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{ ... }`

Comment: Welcome. // Kindly make your code useable for us, e.g. by following these steps: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you.

Comment: Using the TikZ mindmap library might be more flexible

Comment: Thank you! I finally did it with TikZ but I didn't use mindmap lib. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remake of OP answer, this time without use help of Chat-GPT. Resulted code is shorter and more clear:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                calc,
                positioning,}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      base/.style = {circle, draw=white, line width=1.5pt, draw opacity=1,
                     minimum size=#1, align=center, font=\bfseries},
    planet/.style = {base=32mm, fill=orange},
 satellite/.style = {base=13mm, fill=#1, fill opacity=0.7},
  satchild/.style = {base=12mm, fill=green!40, fill opacity=0.7},
                        ]
% Planet
\node (P) [planet] {Interest \\ Areas};
% Satellits
\node   [satellite=blue!30, right=-7mm of P]  {DLTs/\\ Blockchain,\\ Web3};
\node   [satellite=gray!30, above=-7mm of P]  {Big/Fast Data\\ \& Streaming};
\node   [satellite=yellow!30,left=-7mm of P] {Artificial\\ Intelligence};
\node (fp) [satellite=green,below=-7mm of P]  {Functional\\ Programming};
% Satellits children
\node   [satchild, below  left=-4mm and 0mm of fp] {Unison};
\node   [satchild, below right=-4mm and 0mm of fp] {ZIO,\\ Kyo};
\node   [satchild, below=-4mm of fp] {Effect,\\ systems};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From question, is not clear, if image should have own black background. If yes you may add begore `\end{tikzpicture}` the following code lines:

```
% Background, if you like to have it in black
\scoped[on background layer]
    \draw[line width=6mm, fill] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
```

[image]

Comment: code is prose for humans. Very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do it with TikZ with the help of Chat-GPT. Here is the result and the code for reference:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  % Define styles for the nodes
  \tikzstyle{planet}=[circle, fill=orange, minimum size=3.2cm, align=center]
  \tikzstyle{satellite}=[circle, draw, fill=green!40, minimum size=1.3cm, align=center, opacity=0.7, font=\footnotesize, postaction={draw=white, line width=1.5pt, opacity=1}]
  \tikzstyle{satchild}=[circle, draw, fill=green!25, minimum size=0.7cm, align=center, opacity=0.7, font=\footnotesize, postaction={draw=white, line width=1pt, opacity=1}]

  % Draw the central planet
  \node (interests) [planet] {Interest \\ Areas};

  \node (bigdata) [satellite, above=-0.7cm of interests, fill=gray!30] {\textbf{Big/Fast Data} \\ \textbf{\& Streaming}};
  \node (blockchain) [satellite, right=-0.7cm of interests, fill=blue!30] {\textbf{DLTs/} \\ \textbf{Blockchain,} \\ \textbf{Web3}};
  \node (fp) [satellite, below=-0.7cm of interests] {\textbf{Functional} \\ \textbf{Programming}};
  \node (ai) [satellite, left=-0.7cm of interests, fill=yellow!30] {\textbf{Artificial} \\ \textbf{Intelligence}};

  % Sat. children
  \node (unison) [satchild] at ($(fp) + (205:1.4cm)$) {Unison};
  \node (unison) [satchild] at ($(fp) + (-25:1.4cm)$) {ZIO, Kyo};
  \node (unison) [satchild, below=-4mm of fp] {Effect,\\ systems};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like you‘ve been lucky with the code generated. As a general rule I suggest to „train your brain“, not a language model. E.g. what‘s missing here is refactoring, at least for the styles, which not only increases read-ability.

Comment: Kindly have a look at ma refactoring of this ChatGPT-result, which reveals code-noise and other nasty things: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705636/245790 . Software quality can't result from noisy AI ...

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the amount of `code-noise` generated and left by this ChatGPT-approach, here is some refactoring [of the code the OP posted as a solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705626/245790).

As you can see, what's left reveals `some residual nastiness` from the approach chosen. I.e. I'd like to refactor further, e.g. for better read-ability, but the node-statements somehow are good and bad at the same time as they are now. I.e. without much more effort it's hard to make those statements a set of easy to grasp, neatly formatted one-liners.

I also wonder, what happened to the `left-to-right orientation` of the original sketch, which became a bottom-to-top orientation. This may be easier to change now after refactoring than in the GPT-code posted.

I didn't dig into it, but wonder, why the `postaction` is really needed in the SAT and CSAT styles.

`As a rule of thumb`:

- if code has an ugly look&feel, it may be wrong or hard to change
- if code has a neatly arrangement, it's probably more correct, should it compile
- so all these are error-preventing steps, encouraging changes as things evolve.

BTW, `code-noise`, e.g. bad read-ability, is less when you work backwards:

- post nodes etc. first
- introduce style after style
- the code I post now is better but still not good enough from this perspective.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% ~~~ REFACTORING ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% --- removed unused node name ---
% --- removed bold font: not needed ----------
% --- replaced style-names for better read-ability & error prevention ----
% --- moved node names after the style statement (my convention) ---
% --- renamed node names: capitalized, shorter -----
% --- removed calc, replaced shift statements --------------
% --- removed shapes: obviously NOT needed ----------
% --- replaced 0.7cm by 7mm - grasp it at 1 glance w.o. thinking ---
% --- refactoring common styles CMN + removed not needed ones ---------
% --- same for opacity --------
% --- some, still insufficient, reformatting of code ---

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  % Define styles for the nodes
  \tikzstyle{CMN}   = [circle, align=center]
  \tikzstyle{OPC}   = [opacity=0.7]
  \tikzstyle{PAOPC} = [draw=white,opacity=1]
  \tikzstyle{PLANET}= [CMN, fill=orange, minimum size=3.2cm]
  \tikzstyle{SAT}   = [CMN, OPC, fill=green!40, minimum size=1.3cm,
                         font=\footnotesize, 
                         postaction={PAOPC, line width=1.5pt}]
  \tikzstyle{CSAT}  = [CMN, OPC, fill=green!25, minimum size=0.7cm,
                         font=\footnotesize, 
                         postaction={PAOPC, line width=1pt}]

  % Draw the central planet
  \node [PLANET]           (IA)      {Interest\\Areas};
  \node [SAT, above=-7mm of IA, 
        fill=gray!30]                {Big/Fast Data\\\& Streaming};
  \node [SAT, right=-7mm of IA, 
        fill=blue!30]                {DLTs/\\Blockchain,\\Web3};  
  \node [SAT, below=-7mm of IA] (FP) {Functional\\Programming};  
  \node [SAT, left=-7mm of IA, 
        fill=yellow!30]              {Artificial\\Intelligence};

  % Sat. children
  \node [CSAT]              at ([shift=(205:1.4cm)] FP) {Unison};
  \node [CSAT]              at ([shift=(-25:1.4cm)] FP) {ZIO, Kyo};
  \node [CSAT, 
         below=-4mm of FP]                      {Effect,\\systems};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: refactoredResult]

Comment: `\tikzset` instead obsolete `tikzstyle`? Chat-GPT cannot yet compete with a Ti*k*Z user with some experiences (as you have) .

Comment: Thank you @Zarko  . // We now see some kind of core-creation, which received some "embellishment" by the algorithm, which is ok. I tend to summarize, what we also see in this case: it (AI-generated stuff) looks/sounds nice to the layman in a field, and makes a subject matter expert shaking head for a long time. // It may change, hopefully, perhaps, once knowledge can be built-in into todays AI-language models ...